# Graph API call List subscribedSkus states Insufficient privileges while privileges are given

Tags: azure, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-appservice

I try to call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus`

Its documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

And says: `Organization.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Organization.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`

I have made an app on the Azure Portal with the specificed permissions (and more for other API calls):
[image]

- I have waited more then 5 minuts after granting the permissions
- I have even recreated the certificate (which in my knowledge is not needed)
- I can call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{userId}/licenseDetails` successfully

Yet I can't call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus`

I keep getting the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-17T08:55:23",
            "request-id": "xxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Edit: Tried the code of @Rukmini, with again an error of not having enough privaliges:
[image]

Comment: Which grant flow are you using to generate the token?

Comment: I builde the token with the ClientSecretCredential class in c#, with the TennantId, ClientId and ClientSecret (which I get from the certificate)

Comment: I granted the same API permissions as you and I am able to fetch the details successfully. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/mBa9dt2.png).

Comment: If I try  your code exactly, I get an OError with Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Comment: Could you add the error snip?

Comment: I added the snippet, I'm now creating a new App in Azure and see if that changes the situation. I tried the Graph API Explorer where it works well with our tenant. What do you exactly mean with Azure AD Application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254940/discussion-between-rukmini-and-michiel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permission** like below:

[image]

To fetch the **`subscribedSkus`**, I used the below code:

```cs
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "ClientID";
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var result = await graphClient.SubscribedSkus.GetAsync();


Console.WriteLine("Subscribed SKUs:");
foreach (var sku in result.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"SkuId: {sku.SkuId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"SkuName: {sku.AccountName}");
}
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, create a new Azure AD Application and check.

Comment: Creating the a new app with the same permissions helped, so probably the backend showed issues that it should not have.

Comment: Yeah. if you face the issue again with the other applications then you can raise a bug request